# Netlogo: delete list content

Tags: list, netlogo

How do I delete the content of a list in Netlogo?

This is a tuned-down version of my code to function as an example:

```
to calculate_SN
  ask turtles [
    set subjective_norm_list []
    set subjective_norm_list [1 2 3 4 5]
    set subjective_norm ( sum subjective_norm_list / length subjective_norm_list)
    *delete content of subjective_norm_list so that it is empty again*
end
```

The part between asterisks I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `subjective_norm_list` to be an empty list, you can set it to an empty list, just like you did when you initialized it the first time around:

```
set subjective_norm_list []
```

Note that, technically, NetLogo lists are [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), so you're not *deleting* the elements in the list: you're just creating a new list with no elements in it and assigning it to the same variable. But for all intents and purposes, it's the same: `subjective_norm_list` is empty again.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your shared code so far, you should take a different approach: create a function.

```
to-report subjective-norm [#lst]
  report (sum #lst) / (length #lst)
end
```

It is unclear that you will ever need to assign a variable name to your list.  You may be able to use it upon creation and then forget about it.  (It will be garbage collected.)

Comment: Thanks! Loving the to report idea, thanks for the advice. However I'm using the variable for plotting purposes (the total subjective norm is an outcome of my model). But I will use your style for some other fuzzy code I have lying around, merci :)